# React Native - add a new declaration (.d.ts) error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I have a huge problem. I use a node module in my react native project but when I import it, it gives me that error -> `add a new declaration (.d.ts)`

And `bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module`fs`from....`

I think I need to write index.d.ts file but I don't know how can I write and why I have to write.

This is my node modul -> https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-node

Comment: Try to install using following command `npm install react-native-fs --save` then check

Comment: `added 3 packages from 2 contributors and audited 41022 packages in 9.256s
found 7 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details`

Comment: Thats fine, can you try compiling now, your project seems doesn't have all the required npm package.

Comment: no it doesn't work.. same error :/

Comment: Have you installed `iyzipay` by using command `npm install iyzipay` ?

Comment: yes but I think `iyzipay` doesnt for react-native, it is a node.js module

Comment: @Meltem I think you must serve in node and call with fetch in RN.

Comment: @MelihBerberoglu do you know how can I do that? Is there any example?